# What is the simplest way for making a grouped bar chart that calculates the mean of a category in R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, data-manipulation

So I have imported call center data from a csv file into R.

```
flows = read.csv("data.csv")
```

There are two important columns to me:

1. name
2. duration

I am trying to  create  a  bar  chart  that  calculates the average duration of the call for a group, which is divided up by the variable name. Essentially, the chart displays which types of calls have the highest average duration.

There are also about 50 different names, so if I could limit the chart to the top 5/10 that would be ideal. Sorry if this is a simple problem, appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: please share your data and code so we can help further

Comment: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = factor(gear), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean")`

Comment: sorry, the data is confidential.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
   flows %>%
        group_by(name) %>%
        dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(duration, na.rm=TRUE))
```

After this, you probably want to sort it according to duration and keep the 5 first values.

```
flows<-flows[order(flows$Mean),]
flows<-flows[5,]
```